# Perform Action while Button is pressed down?

Tags: objective-c

how can I call a method (in my case the same message over and over again), as long the User presses and holds down a button, and stop performing the action as soon as he releases the button again.
Is it NSButton with Type MomentaryChangedButton?
Im a starter, but if I only knew what Button type to use i could carry on getting more Informations.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Way to make a UIButton continuously fire during a press-and-hold situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903114)