# When i press the button value will increase automatically,how?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Way to make a UIButton continuously fire during a press-and-hold situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903114/way-to-make-a-uibutton-continuously-fire-during-a-press-and-hold-situation)

i have two custom button in camera view, one is zoom in and other one is zoom out both the buttons are pressed value will increase `1,2...` , but i want when i press the zoom in or zoom out button the value will increasing automatically and release the button value will stopped,how? please any one help me

**I tried the code**

```
zoomin=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    zoomin.frame=CGRectMake(60, 410, 60, 60);
    [zoomin setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"zoomplus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [zoomin addTarget:self action:@selector(CameraZoomIn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [buttonView addSubview:zoomin];

-(void)CameraZoomIn
{
    x=x+0.090253;
    y=y+0.090253;
    NSLog(@"X : %f, Y : %f",x,y);
    imgpicker.cameraViewTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(x,y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code..

```
 zoomin = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 zoomin = CGRectMake(60, 410, 60, 60);
 UIImage * zoominImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"zoomplus.png"];
[zoomin setImage:jumpbtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 zoomin.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[zoomin addTarget:self action:@selector(CameraZoomIn) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[zoomin addTarget:self action:@selector(stopZoom) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview: zoomin];
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set `NSTimer`, that will fire every `x` time on `UIControlEventTouchDown` and stop it on `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or `UIControlEventTouchCancel`. When that timer will fire -> do whatever you want with any counter, zoom or any other stuff...