# Continually sending messages from a UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I am making a game at the moment and am having trouble creating a D-Pad. At the moment when I tap a button it will only run once, I don't know which event I can call to make it continually run the code until the player stops touching the button. When I tried using a while loop it just overloads itself and prevents you from touching other buttons. This is the code that I am generally using to move the player and the actual loading of the buttons and such:

```
    - (void) playerMoveLeft
{    
    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img9,img10,img11,img12,img13,img14,img15,img16, nil];

    [imageView setAnimationImages:images];

        NSLog(@"Called left");
        CGRect myFrame = imageView.frame;
        myFrame.origin.x = imageView.frame.origin.x - 5;
        imageView.frame = myFrame;
        [imageView startAnimating];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.6
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(nothingMovingLeft)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:NO];
    [myTimer invalidate];
    myTimer = nil;
}


{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0000.png"];
    img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0001.png"];
    img3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0002.png"];
    img4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0003.png"];
    img5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0004.png"];
    img6 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0005.png"];
    img7 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0006.png"];
    img8 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-e0007.png"];
    img9 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0000.png"];
    img10 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0001.png"];
    img11 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0002.png"];
    img12 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0003.png"];
    img13 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0004.png"];
    img14 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0005.png"];
    img15 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0006.png"];
    img16 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"walking-w0007.png"];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0,180.0,80.0,80.0)];

    NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img7, nil];

    [imageView setAnimationImages:images];

    [imageView setAnimationRepeatCount:100];

    [imageView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    [imageView startAnimating];

    [myView addSubview:imageView];


    moveRight = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [moveRight addTarget:self action:@selector(playerMoveRight) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [moveRight setTitle:@"->" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    moveRight.frame = CGRectMake(200, 280, 60, 60);

    [myView addSubview:moveRight];



    //longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(whichWayToMove:)];

    //longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;

    //[myView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

    moveLeft = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [moveLeft addTarget:self action:@selector(playerMoveLeft) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [moveLeft setTitle:@"<-" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    moveLeft.frame = CGRectMake(30, 280, 60, 60);

    [myView addSubview:moveLeft];

    NSLog(@"Finished setup");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using the timer in your `playerMoveLeft`, you should use the same method in the timer to repeat itself, it will only run one time according to your code. secondly you are setting repeat to `NO`, for repeating use `YES`

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.6
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(playerMoveLeft)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

Read this post, it has both the timer solution and a button with touches solution

[Way to make a UIButton continuously fire during a press-and-hold situation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903114/way-to-make-a-uibutton-continuously-fire-during-a-press-and-hold-situation)

You can manage to set this up for your purposes

Answer (score 1):

USE `NSTimer` for call multiple time with specific `TIME INTERVAL`

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 // You can set TimeInterval as u need.
    target:self
    selector:@selector(targetMethod)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:YES];
```

Call targetMethod method for **2.0 time interval**

```
-(void)targetMethod
{
   // write code for your method
}
```

And You can also stop `NSTimer` by using its method `invalidate`

```
[MyTimer invalidate];
```

For more information about `NSTimer` read [How do I use NSTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449035/how-do-i-use-nstimer)