# UIButton press and hold - repeat action until let go

Tags: ios, uibutton

I want to have a certain method run and repeat itself for as long as someones finger is pressed down on a button. I want that method to stop repeating itself when the finger is not on the button anymore

Is there a way to check if the touchDown is still occurring during the method implementation? Help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Way to make a UIButton continuously fire during a press-and-hold situation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903114/way-to-make-a-uibutton-continuously-fire-during-a-press-and-hold-situation)

Comment: this way worked! thank you. I didn't quite understand it when I read it through before posting this question - second time's a charm.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the `UIControlEventTouchDown` control event to start the method running, and `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`, or similar, to detect when the button is no longer being "pressed".

Set up the actions to the button, e.g.:

```
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startButtonTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(endButtonTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

(Note the above will cause touch up inside and outside the button to invoke the `endButtonTouch:` method.)

Then add the `startButtonTouch:` and `endButtonTouch` methods, e.g., :

```
- (void)startButtonTouch:(id)sender {
    // start the process running...
}

- (void)endButtonTouch:(id)sender {
// stop the running process...
}
```

Comment: This approach will not work if the user taps on the button and move the finger outside the button's bounds.

Comment: Use both `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` and `UIControlEventTouchUpOutside`.  Added to the answer.  If you want to end it when the user drags outside the button, add `UIControlEventTouchDragExit` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing upon the bobnoble's answer here's a helper view

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface YOIDCAutorepeatingButton : UIButton

// you COULD pinch pennies switching to nonatomic, but consider
// how much time it would take to debug if some day some moron decides without checking this spec
// to alter this prop off another thread
@property (atomic) NSTimeInterval delayUntilAutorepeatBegins;
@property NSTimeInterval delayBetweenPresses;

@property (weak) id<NSObject> recipient;
@property SEL touchActionOnRecipient;

@end
```

-------------> .m

```
#import "YOIDCAutorepeatingButton.h"

@interface YOIDCAutorepeatingButton()
{
NSTimeInterval _pressStartedAt;
}

@end

@implementation YOIDCAutorepeatingButton


- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
if (self) {
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(startButtonTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [self addTarget:self action:@selector(endButtonTouch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];

    self.delayUntilAutorepeatBegins = .250;
    self.delayBetweenPresses = .080;
}
return self;
}

-(void)killLastCharacter:(id)sender
{
[self.recipient performSelector:self.touchActionOnRecipient withObject:sender];
}

- (void)performAutorepeat:(id)sender
{
if(!self.delayBetweenPresses) {
    // bail
    return;
}
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(self.delayBetweenPresses * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(_pressStartedAt) {
        [self killLastCharacter:sender];
        [self performAutorepeat:sender];
    }
});
}

- (void)startButtonTouch:(id)sender {

[self killLastCharacter:sender];
NSTimeInterval now = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
_pressStartedAt = now;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(self.delayUntilAutorepeatBegins * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if(_pressStartedAt) {
        [self killLastCharacter:sender];
        [self performAutorepeat:sender];
    }
});
}

- (void)endButtonTouch:(id)sender {
_pressStartedAt = 0;
}

@end
```

-------- sample usage -------

```
- (IBAction)killLastDigit:(id)sender {
```

.....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
assert(self.backSpace);
[YOIDCAutorepeatingButton class]; // if xib is in a bundle other than main gottal load the class
// otherwise you'd get -[UIButton setRecipient:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
// on setRecipient:
self.backSpace.recipient = self;
self.backSpace.touchActionOnRecipient = @selector(killLastDigit:);
```