# Keep calling function as long as finger is pressed down

Tags: ios, objective-c

Right now I'm using:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Function called");
}
```

which activates on press down, which is correct. But, I also want to continue calling the function, let's say every second, as long as the finger is still on the screen (in other words: until the finger is lifted up).

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Start timer when touch down and end timer when touch up.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903114/way-to-make-a-uibutton-continuously-fire-during-a-press-and-hold-situation

Comment: @CrimsonChris Oh, yea hadn't even thought of using NSTimer.